# Как задать направление частиц? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Не могу решить проблему. Дана струя воды, сделанная в Particle System, как мне заставить протекать струю по спирали которая идет левее струи. Под частицы подложил Plane с коллайдером чтобы струя не падала вниз, но дальше она не идет. Возможно ли как-то самому задавать направление и форму движения частиц?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: юнити под рукой нету но чисто теоретически возможно в настройку Shape задать кастомный обьект.

Comment: Я выбрал в Shape тип Mesh Render спирали моей, там какая-то фигня рисуется

Comment: вероятно нужно донастроить. Ознакомся с видеотуториалами в интернете как настраивать партикл систем в общем и целом. Просмотри видосиков 5 хотя бы а потом уже пытайся настраивать сам

Comment: Вот тебе нормальный урок по системе частиц [ссылка](https://youtu.be/7g-dNwB6-pU) . Долговато, немного может быть нудно, но зато просто и понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesh это набор точек и полигонов, там нет направлений, никаких спиралей. Выбрав Shape Mesh, можно указать только зону спавна внутри меша и всё.

Вам нужно движение частиц по цепочке кривых `Curve Spline`! `Particle System` таких функций не имеет. Вам придётся писать это руками. Создайте pool спрайтов, повёрнутых на камеру, двигающихся по [кривым Безье](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/) с разбросом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]